# Paypal REST Apis and mobile devices

Tags: paypal, responsive-design

I am making a responsive website that will look good on both mobile devices and desktop computers. I am using Paypal REST Api for my checkout. I have been looking and I cant seem to find an answer to my question. On a mobile responsive website, will Paypal's REST Api work when accessed from a iphone or ipad like it does when on a desktop or do I need other code specifically for mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST has nothing to do with device and will work exactly the same.

Comment: Nice! Thanks that helps me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

While rest will work on a mobile device it is not responsive. I wish PapPal would make it responsive, it seems a simple thing to do.
I am using it on many sites but I think it is costing me sales on mobile devices especially if they are using credit card.